# Asymptotics of $\ln T$ and $\ln( \ln T)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I know that $\ln(\ln T)/\ln T\to0$ as $T\to \infty$. In my case, I'm evaluating 
$$\lim_{T\to\infty}\frac{(\ln \ln T)^{2/3}}{(\ln T)^\delta}$$
for some $\delta\in(0,1/6)$.

I think that if the following holds
$$\lim_{T\to\infty}\frac{\ln \ln T}{(\ln T)^\Delta}=0,$$
for any $\Delta>0$, then I can conclude that the limit I'm seeking is zero.
Although I cannot prove this general result.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed the case, because $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln x}{x^\Delta}=0$ and hence we have for any sequence $(x_T)_T$ that diverges to infinity that $\lim_{T\to \infty} \ln x_T / x_T^\Delta=0$.

In particular then for $x_T=\ln T$.

Comment: Yes! I was thinking about it.  I know it is obvious that $\lim_{\ln T\to\infty} f(\ln T)=\lim_{T\to\infty} f(\ln T)$, but how to argue it?

Comment: I'vs added some more details in an edit. I'm not sure whether you already saw them.

Comment: I saw it now. It makes sense! Thanks